# Unable to pass object as an argument

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, object

HTML and inline JS code:

```
<a onclick='show(user)'>${user.firstName + " " + user.lastName}</a>
```

Inside this show function I am passing an object User which has 5-6 properties,  but when I used debugger it is not showing me as an object.

I also tried this , and this is showing be user as object in debugger but I am getting uncaught syntax error.

```
<a onclick='show(${user})'>${user.firstName + " " + user.lastName}</a>
```

I want to pass it as object so that i can utilise its properties.

```js
const displayUsers = (users) => {
    const htmlString = users
        .map((user) => {
            debugger;
            return `
            <li>
                <a onclick='show(user)'>${user.firstName + " " + user.lastName}</a>
                
            </li>
        `;
        })
        .join('');
    usersList.innerHTML = htmlString;

    console.log(users, 'list')
    // console.log(htmlString)
};
function show(user)
{
    alert(user);
 console.log( user.aonId);

};
```

Comment: That's the disadvantage with working with HTML strings: You cannot easily serialize complex data into it. I suggest to learn how to create DOM elements and bind event handlers with the DOM API.

Comment: is the Users an Array or an Object. You can use the map function over Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

What if you set the data attribute in the button with the json stringified, and then add a listener for all your button, on click parse the data attribute and access it.

Example:

```js
const displayUsers = (users) => {
  const htmlString = users
    .map((user) => {
      return `
            <li>
                <a data-user=${JSON.stringify(user)}>${user.firstName + " " + user.lastName}</a>  
            </li>
        `;
    })
    .join('');
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = htmlString;

};

displayUsers([{
  firstName: 'George',
  lastName: 'Michael'
}, {
  firstName: 'Bruce',
  lastName: 'Springsteen'
}]);

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-user]');

buttons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function show(event) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(event.currentTarget.dataset.user)); // <---- Use data 
  });
})
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to use methods or properties of elements then you should resort to creating elements using DOM methods, like [`Document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).

This will enable you to add event listeners, reference values and more.

The following example loops over each user in the `users` array and creates the structure you currently have in your string. An event listener is attached, the text is set and the elements build.

In the end everything is collected in a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) instance which allows you to append all created user elements in a single sweep to improve performance.

> Because all of the nodes are inserted into the document at once, only one reflow and render is triggered instead of potentially one for each node inserted if they were inserted separately.

The fragment is then appended to your `usersList` element.

```
const displayUsers = (users) => {
  const fragment = new DocumentFragment();

  users.forEach(user => {
    const { firstName, lastName } = user;

    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    const anchor = document.createElement('a');

    anchor.addEventListener('click', event => show(user, event));
    anchor.textContent = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;

    listItem.append(anchor);
    fragment.append(listItem);
  });

  usersList.append(fragment);
};
```

Comment: Answers can be accepted by clicking the checkmark at the top left of the answer. This will future readers with the same question know what the correct answer is and gives us fake internet points as a reward.